# Reverting an incomplete set of operations

Tags: undo

What is the preferred method of reverting a partially applied set of operations within a function?  For example in a function that kills some text, performs some intervening operations, and then yanks the earlier killed text-- if one of those intervening operations throws an error the originally killed text should be restored by the function.

Are there are any generalized solutions like SQL transactions for this?    I know Emacs has a powerful undo system, but I have not used it programmatically.

Comment: killing for immediate yanking in the same function sounds like you're doing it wrong. Killing is meant for interactive use, see second paragraph in `(info "(elisp) The Kill Ring")`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for `unwind-protect` or `condition-case`.

The former is for doing cleanup unconditionally. The latter is for handling errors - in general or of specific types.

---

**`unwind-protect`:**

```
unwind-protect is a special form in `C source code'.

(unwind-protect BODYFORM UNWINDFORMS...)

Do BODYFORM, protecting with UNWINDFORMS.
If BODYFORM completes normally, its value is returned
after executing the UNWINDFORMS.
If BODYFORM exits nonlocally, the UNWINDFORMS are executed anyway.
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Cleanups](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cleanups.html).

---

**`condition-case`:**

```
condition-case is a special form in `C source code'.

  (condition-case VAR BODYFORM &rest HANDLERS)

Regain control when an error is signaled.
Executes BODYFORM and returns its value if no error happens.
Each element of HANDLERS looks like (CONDITION-NAME BODY...)
where the BODY is made of Lisp expressions.

A handler is applicable to an error
if CONDITION-NAME is one of the error's condition names.
If an error happens, the first applicable handler is run.

The car of a handler may be a list of condition names instead of a
single condition name; then it handles all of them.  If the special
condition name `debug' is present in this list, it allows another
condition in the list to run the debugger if `debug-on-error' and the
other usual mechanisms says it should (otherwise, `condition-case'
suppresses the debugger).

When a handler handles an error, control returns to the `condition-case'
and it executes the handler's BODY...
with VAR bound to (ERROR-SYMBOL . SIGNAL-DATA) from the error.
(If VAR is nil, the handler can't access that information.)
Then the value of the last BODY form is returned from the `condition-case'
expression.

See also the function `signal' for more info.
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Handling Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html).